# new URL() in javascript give results differently for different protocols

Tags: javascript

The hostname returned in both the cases is different. Is there a way to get the hostname and pathname consistently regardless of the protocol used. The hostname and pathname are similar for http/ftp, but for others, it is different.

```
url1 = new URL("atp://abcd.com/person/items/1234")
URL{
    hash: ""
    host: ""
    hostname: ""
    href: "atp://abcd.com/person/items/1234"
    origin: "null"
    password: ""
    pathname: "//abcd.com/person/items/1234"
    port: ""
    protocol: "atp:"
    search: ""
}
url2 = new URL("http://abcd.com/person/items/1234")
URL{
    hash: ""
    host: "abcd.com"
    hostname: "abcd.com"
    href: "http://abcd.com/person/items/1234"
    origin: "http://abcd.com"
    password: ""
    pathname: "/person/items/1234"
    port: ""
    protocol: "http:"
    search: ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Many schemes don't have an host at all, see e.g [data: URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs), and the [URL standards](https://url.spec.whatwg.org) can't be responsible for every schemes out there, they only handle a small subset, the ones used on the web.

You can still hack around the situation if you are sure your URL does have an hostname by replacing the protocol of your parsed URL:

```js
const getHostName = (url) => {
  const parsed = new URL(url);
  parsed.protocol = "http";
  return parsed.hostname;
}

console.log(getHostName("atp://abcd.com/person/items/1234"));
```